# jquery div and class selector

Tags: jquery, class, css-selectors

Here is a jsFiddle[1](http://jsfiddle.net/wPgq3/) and here is my code and PHP:

```
<div id="" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/">Αρχική</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="">

</div>

<div id="events" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png" /><a href="/events">Εκδηλώσεις-Νέα</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="events">

<div id="educational_events" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/events/educational_events">Εκπαιδευτικές Εκδηλώσεις</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="educational_events">

</div>

<div id="announcements" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/events/announcements">Ανακοινώσεις</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="announcements">

</div>

<div id="party" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/events/party">Party-Χοροί</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="party">

</div>

<div id="various" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/events/various">Λοιπές δραστηριότητες</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="various">

</div></div>

<div id="proposals" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png" /><a href="/proposals">Προτάσεις</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="proposals">

<div id="dap_hmmy" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/proposals/dap_hmmy">Προτάσεις ΔΑΠ-ΝΔΦΚ ΗΜΜΥ</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="dap_hmmy">

</div>

<div id="dap_emp" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/proposals/dap_emp">Προτάσεις ΔΑΠ-ΝΔΦΚ ΕΜΠ</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="dap_emp">

</div>

<div id="dap_aei" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/proposals/dap_aei">Προτάσεις ΔΑΠ-ΝΔΦΚ ΑΕΙ</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="dap_aei">

</div></div>

<div id="lessons" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png" /><a href="/lessons">Μαθήματα</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="lessons">

<div id="1_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png" /><a href="/lessons/1_semester/">1<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="1_semester">

<a href="/lessons/1_semester/games.html">O titlos tou arthrou</a></div>

<div id="2_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/lessons/2_semester">2<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="2_semester">

</div>
 <div id="3_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/lessons/3_semester">3<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>
</div><div class="submenu_more" id="3_semester"> 
</div>
<div id="4_semester" class="submenu">
<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/lessons/4_semester">4<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="4_semester">

</div>

<div id="5_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/lessons/5_semester">5<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="5_semester">

</div>

<div id="courses_flows" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/lessons/courses_flows">Μαθήματα ροών</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="courses_flows">
    </div></div>
  </div><div style="float:right;width:325px;overflow:hidden;"><div id="notes" class="menu">
    <img align="absmiddle" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png" /><a href="/notes">Σημειώσεις-Παλιά Θέματα</a>
    </div><div class="menu_more" id="notes">
    <div id="1_semester" class="submenu">
    <img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/notes/1_semester">1<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>
    </div><div class="submenu_more" id="1_semester">
    </div>
    <div id="2_semester" class="submenu">
    <img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/notes/2_semester">2<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>
    </div><div class="submenu_more" id="2_semester">
    </div>

<div id="3_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/notes/3_semester">3<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="3_semester">

</div>

<div id="4_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/notes/4_semester">4<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="4_semester">

</div>

<div id="5_semester" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/notes/5_semester">5<sup>o</sup> εξάμηνο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="5_semester">

</div>

<div id="courses_flows" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/notes/courses_flows">Μαθήματα ροών</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="courses_flows">

</div></div>

<div id="radio" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/radio">Radio</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="radio">

</div>

<div id="contact" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/contact">Επικοινωνία</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="contact">

</div>

<div id="services" class="menu">

<img align="absmiddle" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png" /><a href="/services">Υπηρεσίες</a>

</div><div class="menu_more" id="services">

<div id="terms_of_use" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/services/terms_of_use">Όροι χρήσης</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="terms_of_use">

</div>

<div id="privacy" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/services/privacy">Προσωπικό απόρρητο</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="privacy">

</div>

<div id="statistics" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/services/statistics">Στατιστικά Ιστοτόπου</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="statistics">

</div>

<div id="sitemap" class="submenu">

<img align="absmiddle" class="inactive" src="http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus_disabled.png" /><a href="/services/sitemap">Xml Sitemap</a>

</div><div class="submenu_more" id="sitemap">

</div>

</div>

</div><br>
```

This will be something like a sitemap.  The problem is that I can't catch `.submenu_more` class which has a specific `id`.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu img, .submenu img").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("class")=="inactive")
            return false;
        var id_clicked=$(this).parent().attr("id");
        var class_clicked=$(this).parent().attr("class");
        visib_clicked=$("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked).css("visibility");
        //alert($("."+class_clicked+"_more"+"#1_semester").length);
        if(visib_clicked=="visible"){
            $("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+", ."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+">*").css("visibility","hidden");
            $("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+", ."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+">*").css("position","absolute");
            $(this).attr("src","http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/plus.png");
        }else{
            $("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+", ."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+">*").css("visibility","visible");
            $("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+", ."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked+">*").css("position","relative");
            $(this).attr("src","http://dap.ntua.gr/el/img/minus.png");
        }
    });
});
```

Try to hit 1o εξάμηνο in jsfiddle to see the problem.  Don't hit the text. Hit the image right to the text.

```
visib_clicked=$("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked).css("visibility");
```

Works fine if I click `.menu img` class, but doesn't work for `.submenu img` class...

An example:

```
<div id="some_id_1" class="menu">
<img src="some_src.png"/>
<a href="something">Some text</a>
<div id="same_id with_parent=some_id_1" class="menu_more">
blabla_goes here
</div>
```

I want when i click the image .menu_more with id=some_id_1 div disapearead..
Something similar and for submenu and submenu_more..
For menu,menu_more my code works,
Doesn't work for submenu,submenu_more..

I found the problem..
The problem is into the name of id

```
id="1_semester" doesn't work
```

`id="semester"` works!!
Why is that?
I don't want to change id's of my elements if it's not necessery

Comment: One-line HTML is **very** hard to read.

Comment: yes but you can see it into jsfidle, i can post 70 lines of php that gives this html if you want

Comment: Even in your jsFiddle, there are no line-breaks or indentations.  Properly format your HTML code or nobody is going to want to help you.

Comment: agree, plaese reformat the HTML so that it's on more lines, make it easier for people to help you

Comment: i have just add php code..Hope that helps

Comment: Could you also please trim it all down to the bare essentials? Not only does it help us but you may also spot the problem. Formatting your HTML might also help you spot your own problem.

Comment: I think people mean using something like this http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier

Comment: That's no good... we need to see properly formatted HTML.  You expect us to put more effort into an answer than you're willing to put into the question?

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do there.

```
var id_clicked=$(this).parent().attr("id");
var class_clicked=$(this).parent().attr("class");
visib_clicked=$("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked).css("visibility");
```

if id_clicked is the id of the parent, and class_clicked is the class of the parent, isn't $("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked) just... the parent!? you can only have one ID once in a document

also, instead of

```
visib_clicked=$("."+class_clicked+"_more#"+id_clicked).css("visibility");
    if(visib_clicked=="visible"){
     ....
```

you can have

```
$( something:visible ).css({
    position : ...
  , visibility ...
})

$( something:hidden ).css({
    position : ...
  , visibility ...
})
```

Comment: i will write a simple example of what this code want to do, into my original post

Comment: no!! it's not the parent.. i have _more into the line of code witch is not in `code_tag` in your answer above